# Convert a MultipleMonitor Application From WinForms to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I've got a little problem and tried to solve it now for nearly 6 to 8 hours but I didn't find any matching answer. I'm a complete newbie to WPF, so please point me any errors I made.

At first I have the following in my App.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfVideowand
{
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    ...
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Screen MyScreen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
      {
        List<string> MyStrings = Xml.GetScreens(i);
        if (MyStrings[1] == "true")
        {
          OpenWindow(MyScreen, MyStrings[0], i);
        }
        i++;
        Shelf MyShelf = new Shelf(MyScreen, i, MyStrings[0]);
        MyShelf.Show();
      }
    }
    private void OpenWindow(System.Windows.Forms.Screen myScreen, string configName, int screenNumber)
    {
      Shelf NewShelf = new Shelf(myScreen, screenNumber, configName);
    }
  }
}
```

And inside the Shelf.xaml.cs it looks this way:

```
namespace WpfVideowand
{
  public partial class Shelf : Window
  {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
    System.Windows.Forms.Screen _Screen { get; set; }
    ...
    public Shelf(System.Windows.Forms.Screen myScreen, int screenNumber, string configName)
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      _Screen = myScreen;
      ShowOnMonitor(screenNumber);
      ...
    }
    private void ShowOnMonitor(int screenNumber)
    {
      System.Windows.Forms.Screen[] ScreenArray;
      ScreenArray = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;
      int XCoord = Convert.ToInt32(ScreenArray[screenNumber].Bounds.Left);
      this.Left = XCoord;
      int YCoord = Convert.ToInt32(ScreenArray[screenNumber].Bounds.Top);
      this.Top = XCoord;
      IntPtr active = GetActiveWindow();
      System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(window => new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle == active).Name = "Monitor" + screenNumber.ToString();
      System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(window => new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle == active).WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

The way described above worked fine in Windows Forms Application. In WPF I have the problem, that I get the error message, that rectangle (the window) would have no Top or Left property.

I even tried it in some other ways, like creating with

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen _screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromControl(this);
```

an object, that would have .Top and .Left. But there I get the message, that I cannot convert a Shelf-object into a System.Windows.Forms.Control.
Anyone a suggestion, how I could make my Screens appear on the monitor where it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it myself...
For anyone who is interested in finding some answers to this problem here it is:
At first, see that you have the correct reference implemented. For this you need System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms. (Afterwards you have to declare many things explicit, like System.Windows.Controls.Button instead of Button, etc.)
Then see that you start the app with something like Startup="Application_Startup" and not an uri, because you want to start many forms and not only one.
Afterwards be absolutly sure to NOT set the Windowstyle to maximized in the XAML (this did cost me nearly 4 hours. In between i grew 56 grey hairs). Use this in the Code-Behind:
System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType().SingleOrDefault(window => new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle == active).WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;